# Best way to map over asynchronous data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where I want to map over an array of data, like this:

```
render() {

  return (
    <List>
        {this.props.data.days.map(function(item){
          return (
            <ListItem>Hej</ListItem>
          );
        })}
    </List>
  );
}
```

`props.data` is asynchronous data fetched at the parent component and passed down as state to this component. That means that when this component is first rendered, `this.props.data`is undefined and I get an error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. What is the preferred way to handle this? Should I do something in the different life cycles or in the constructor?

I am not using Flux or Redux.

I have tried setting default propTypes, like this:

```
class SingleCompetition extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    data: { days: [] },
  }

  render() {
    let competition = this.props.data;

    return (
      <List heading="sunday 150 starts">
        {this.props.data.days.map(function(item){
          return (
            <ListItem>Hej</ListItem>
          );
        })}
      </List>
    );
  }
}
```

But then I get this error: `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$pnbhyoz0ysdjwgvypz8q9qkt9' of null`

Answer (score 1):

I am using `getDefaultProps` method.

In your case it would be like:

```
 getDefaultProps: function () {
        return { 
            data: {
                days: []
            }
        };
  },
```

You can read more about these methods [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html).

**Update**:

Thanks for the comments, here is my updated answer for ES6. If you're using ES6, I guess it should look like this:

```
class SingleCompetition extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    data: { days: ['monday', 'tuesday'] },
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.data.days.map(function(day){
              return <li>{day}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
    );
}

React.render(<SingleCompetition />, document.body);
```

Comment: these methods are deprecated in es6

Comment: I actually tried this, but I get an error writing exactly this. I have updated my question with it

Comment: @DanCantir did you see my comment?

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {

return (
  <List>
    {this.props.data !== undefined ? this.props.data.days.map(function(item){
      return (
        <ListItem>Hej</ListItem>
        );
      })
   : null}
  </List>
 );
}
```

Comment: Or replace `null` with `Busy loading <img src="spinner.gif" />` or whatever you want to show the user while the data loads.

Comment: This works best if the data is passed as state from a parent component, since setting a default state in the parent seems to override the default props

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
{this.props.data !== undefined? this.props.data.map(){}: null}
```

Answer (score 0):

dan-cantir's method using getDefaultProps is probably the smoothest way. If you're using ES6 classes:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
    data: {
        days: []
    }
}
```

Or, using stateless functional components:

```
function MyComponent({ data = { days: [] } }) {
    ...
}
```